I am using React-Naitve expo. How much faster will it be if I build with a pro account related to eas build?
I discovered expo while using react-native cli. We created a nerfed navigation section, a few pages, and proceeded to extract the APK files. However, when I extracted the apk file using eas build, I found out the surprising fact that it took about 10 to 13 minutes.
So I suddenly wondered

How much faster will the build speed be if I proceed with a pro account?
They say that the queue priority will be increased. What are the conditions for giving priority?
I wonder how much of a difference there is in speed after the queue gets higher.

I am thinking about the payment system for my pro account.
What are the other benefits of using a pro account?
I'm asking a question because it's difficult to understand just from the text written at https://expo.dev/pricing.
Is there something else I don't know about other than just making it easier to build and faster?
I heard that the speed is faster, so I'm curious about the difference in speed between the pro account and the free plan.
Thank you in advance to everyone who responded. have a good day
